# Trying to create an animated graph, am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated' error

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the voltage/current coming out of a device, with these being written to a file and then displayed on the same plot, which updates in real time. Currently the code does this, but it pops up with an error message each time the graph updates which seems to be slowing the pace at which the program takes measurements.

The error seems to be occurring each time the graph updates i.e. when **plt.draw()** is executed within the While loop, making me think that it occurs in **def animate_readings(i)**, though I've included all pertinent pieces of code just in case.

```
plt.ion()

...



fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.clear()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.clear()
plt.xlim(-7,3)
ax1.set_ylabel('Voltage V')
ax2.set_ylabel('Current mA')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5,27)
ax2.set_ylim(-5, 400, 10)
Vpatch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Voltage')
Cpatch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Current')
plt.legend(handles=[Vpatch, Cpatch]) 
plt.draw()
plt.pause(0.1)

"Is used to assign properties to the graph used in FuncAnimation"

def animate_readings(i):

    plt.xlim(c-8,c+2)
    ax1.plot(AVdata, color='b')
    ax2.plot(ACdata, color='r')
    Artists = namedtuple ('Artists', ('AVdata', 'ACdata'))
    returnable = Artists(
    ax1.plot(AVdata, color='b'),
    ax2.plot(ACdata, color='r')
    )
    return returnable

...

while 1:

    print 1  

    "Below if statement names and creates file at beginning of operation"

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_readings, interval=200,    blit=True)

...        

    if c % 1 == 0:
        print "2b"
        try:
            plt.draw() 
            plt.pause(0.1)
            print "2c"
        except :
            pass
        print 2

    c = c + 1
```

The error which pops up after **print "2b"** executes is as follows. Nominally the loop should be running ~3x a second but, due to the error it only runs every 3 seconds and, in a recent extended test, only recorded readings every 30 seconds.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 388, in process
   proxy(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 228, in __call__
return mtd(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1026, in _start
self._init_draw()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1750, in _init_draw
self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1778, in _draw_frame
a.set_animated(self._blit)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
```

Comment: does the program print 2c or does it crash?

Comment: `ax.plot` returns a tuple. Try `returnable = Artists(ax1.plot(AVdata, color='b')[0], ax2.plot(ACdata, color='r')[0])`

Comment: In addition to ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion, I'm confused by the fact that you are running `FuncAnimation` inside an infinite loop, that does not seem to be the right way to use it,

Comment: @JakeP The program prints 2b, displays the error, then prints 2c.

Comment: @DizietAsahi I'm quite new to Python and haven't done anything this complicated before, so this code is likely far from ideal in how its structured. Would it running in the loop be detrimental to the codes functionality?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily causing the error, but it is definitely not common practice. Since your code is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I cannot say whether there is a better way to structure your code. Maybe see [this post, which looks close to what you are trying to do]

Comment: @DizietAsahi Did you mean to attach a link to the end of your last comment? If so it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Apologies. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619953/1356000